# Changing the design of Myaccount page

Tags: magento2.3, css, phtml, help-wanted, myaccount

We have designed My account page using HTML. Now we have to implement the same design on our website.

In order to get the same design, where I have to modify the CSS?

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you created any custom theme ?

Comment: No, we have extended the luma theme

Comment: Yes, means in app/design directory you've replicated Luma theme Right ?

Comment: We haven't placed all the files and folders on our theme. Also, please tell me in which file I have to modify the CSS.

Comment: It means you have your custom theme in app/design/ directory. Am I Right ? So, I'll let you know how can you add your custom css there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Please confirm whether the path is right app/design/vendor/module/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/module.less

Comment: You can add your custom css as well, if you do not want to add in less file.

Comment: Ok. Do I need to add class names in corresponding template file?

Comment: I'm adding solution in answer in few mins

Comment: Thank you. I'm waiting for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this file in your custom theme here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" media="screen" />
   </head>
</page>
```

- After adding above xml file you can create your **custom.css** here..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/custom.css

You can add your css in above file.

- After doing this please run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

- And refresh your frontend. You can see your custom css there.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try and update you

Comment: Okay let me know, if this solution works for you then. :)

Comment: Please approve this answer if this solution will works for you. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I will do it. I have some query. When we create myaccount design in html, we have added our own class names. Now we can add these class on our Magento.?

Comment: @Siva, Can you please let me know where you want to add classes ?

Comment: I'll help you here if you have any query.

Comment: I have tried as you said but that's not working. Now tried with <css rel='stylesheet'  src="css/custom.css"   media='all'/> and it works. May I know what's the difference from your code to the code I mentioned here?

Comment: May be that was **media="screen"** and **media="all"**. Really not sure, but that is working correctly with screen in my case everytime. :)

Comment: You can approve my answer, if that answer was helpful to you. ;)

Comment: Yes, I have approved. I have asked a question related to Myaccount dashboard https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293257/magento2-3-how-to-create-separate-myaccount-dashboard Can you please help?

Comment: Yes, sure. I'll help you. but you need to go here step by step, first you need to check only dashboard for different types of customers.

Comment: Then after you can think about tabs. otherwise first check tabs and then check different dashboard pages